# cin skipping variables after entering name

Tags: c++, input

I get an error when I try to run this. It lets me input the employee's name, and then once I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it skips to the end, flying by hours and pay rate without letting me input them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()  
    {
        string EmployeeName;    //Employee Name
        float EmployeeHours;
        float EmployeePayRate; //Emplyee Hours, Employee PayRate

        cout << setw(50) << "Employee Name: ";
        cin >> EmployeeName;

        cout << setw(50) << "EmployeeHours: ";
        cin >> EmployeeHours;

        cout << setw(50) << "EmployeePayRate: ";
        cin >> EmployeePayRate;

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you possibly enteirng the name as multiple words? If you are, that may be the issue. The EmployeeName gets only the first word, while the rest is forwarded to the other inputs.

Answer (score 3):

I think the comment by @AleksandarStojadinovic provides the clue to your problem. Use

```
std::getline(std::cin, EmployeeName);
```

to read the name. Rest can be as they are.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having an error when I try to run this. It lets me input the
>   employees name, and then once you press enter it skips to the end.
>   flies by hours and pay rate without letting me input that.

Your name must be comprised of two/three names, maybe first middle and last or something like that. `cin` deals space separated string and `enter` separated string in the same way i.e it will take each space separated `string` as different input. And for that if your name has two names, the first one goes right but the second one goes to a variable which is declared as `float` and the program terminates abnormally. That's why using cin in this case isn't right at all.

You need to use another way to avoid that, like using `getline(cin,EmployeeName)` .

Comment: _"`cin` takes space as `enter` not as a regular string"_ ... you should explain this better, because as currently written it's nonsense. And why do you think it needs three names to cause the problem, isn't there a space if you just have a first name and last name?

Comment: Yes, a little bit better, but _"`cin` takes space as `enter` not as a regular string"_ is still nonsense. It reads a space as space, not as something else. Why not just say "reading a string from an `istream` only reads up to the first whitespace character"?

Comment: Of course it reads space as space. That's the technical truth. But I didn't mean it like that, I was simply trying to convince that for cin, space separated inputs are dealt like enter(new line) separated inputs, without going for any technical explanation. I thought that would be easier for the OP to understand.

Comment: And what does "like enter(new line) separated inputs" mean? It seems to me that's based on a completely bogus understanding of "enter(new line) separated inputs" which is not relevant to C++. You might as well say "space is handled like flurblegarb" and then say "oh, but I meant it's handled the way flurblegarb is on the planet Magrathea"